Access to a Circle CI project environment variable from Android project codebase
I have created the environment variable MY_API_KEY in Circle CI (under project settings), but how to get it and use it in Android project codebase?
I have added the following lines in my module's build.gradle file of the Android project:
android {

    def myApiKey = " "
    if (System.env.MY_API_KEY != null) {
        myApiKey = "${System.env.MY_API_KEY}"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField("String", "MY_API_KEY", "\"$myApiKey\"")
    }
}

And then, as far as I understand, I need to export the environment variable during the build process - and so I've added the following
code to .circleci/config.yml file:
aliases:
  - &create_my_api_key
    run:
      name: Create My Api Key
      command: echo 'export MY_API_KEY=$MY_API_KEY' >> $BASH_ENV
...

jobs:
  build-for-tests:
    steps:
      - *export_my_api_key

And then I thought I should be able to access it in my Android code via BuildConfig (as BuildConfig.MY_API_KEY), but I don't see it in my module's generated BuildConfig.java file (the field does not exist in the file)... I did a gradle sync, but nothing changed.
So my question is: is it possible to get access to an environment variable from Circle CI in a local run of Android project? And if it's possible, what should I do additionally to get this access?

"I don't see it in my module's generated BuildConfig.java file" -- do you mean that BuildConfig.MY_API_KEY does not exist, or that BuildConfig.MY_API_KEY exists but is the empty string or something?

@CommonsWare I meant that BuildConfig.MY_API_KEY does not exist (while BuildConfig file is present, of course)

Did you opt into adding to BuildConfig via buildFeatures.buildConfig = true in the android closure of your build.gradle file?

@CommonsWare yes, buildFeatures.buildConfig is set to true
